# Initialise a dict of empty lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am trying to initialise a dict of empty lists in order to append to them, however this has led to some strange behaviour:

```
def solution(A):
    d = dict.fromkeys(set(A), [])
    for i in range(len(A)):
        d[A[i]].append(i)
    print(d)
```

input:

```
[3, 4, 3, 2, 3, -1, 3, 3]
```

output:

```
{2: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
 3: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
 4: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
-1: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]}
```

`dict.fromkeys` seems to initialise all lists as a pointer to the same list under the hood, is this what is happening? How can I know this would be the behaviour/why would this be the behaviour? Is there a way to tell the interpreter not to do this?

Comment: [`defaultdict(list)`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) can be used here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I know this would be the behaviour

The [Python documentation says it](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys) and warns you:

> classmethod fromkeys(*iterable*[, *value*])
>
> Create a new dictionary with keys from *iterable* and values set to *value*.
>
> `fromkeys()` is a class method that returns a new dictionary. *value* defaults to `None`. All of the values refer to just a single instance,
>   so **it generally doesn’t make sense for *value* to be a mutable object
>   such as an empty list**. To get distinct values, use a dict
>   comprehension instead.

Answer (score 1):

All your lists are the same object. `[]` is just a literal expression that gets evaluated before it is passed to the [`dict.fromkeys`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys). How can the function know how to duplicate any random object?

If you want that behaviour, choose a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

def solution(A):
    d = defaultdict(list)  # `list` is a factory funtion that can be called repeatedly
    for i in range(len(A)):
        d[A[i]].append(i)
    print(d)
    # or, if you dislike the output (note, it is a dict already)
    # print(dict(d))
```

Comment: it is not the behaviour but why would i expect it not to be able to copy?

Comment: You can pass any object, custom and all (could be a class or a function or whatever). The operation "copy" is not generally defined. Not every type has a `copy` method like `list`.

Answer (score 0):

In fromkeys, if the value provided is mutable (like a list) each key's value will be a reference to the same object, hence all of the values being updated at once. You can test this by appending to the original list to yield the same result as you'd been getting:

```py
def solution(A):
    lst = []
    d = dict.fromkeys(set(A), lst)
    for i in range(len(A)):
        lst.append(i)
    print(d)
```

Apart from other answers provided, you could go the dictionary comprehension route:

```py
def solution(A):
    d = { key : [] for key in A }
    for i in range(len(A)):
        d[A[i]].append(i)
    print(d)
```